QGIS Server logging to STDERR
Since QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE is deprecated on QGIS Server I want to change to QGIS_SERVER_LOG_STDERR link.
So I commented out the Logfile part and added the STDERR part to my httpd-fcgid.conf. But I can't find out if and where the logs are stored. It worked fine and the server didn´t log to the logfile anymore. But where do the logs go and how can I read them?

Where is your HTTP server logging to?

Like @bugmenot123 hinted, the QGIS Server logs can be seen in the logs of the HTTP Server. In my case in the Apache Server logs.
